# How to test NEW_USER handler in JOVO , with google home

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, jovo-framework

I am developing a new google home app. The google action is written in Dialogflow. The web hook is written in node js using JOVO framework. The action requires account linking with OAUTH.

I am trying to simulate and test "first time user" or "new user". In JOVO this is handled with a handler called NEW_USER.

I am looking to create the correct testing conditions so NEW_USER is triggered, unable to do so. Tried the following

1) https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7126338?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en - this contains a section in Step 2 to unlink the app. This does not work as described , as my action is yet unpublished I do not see it in the section as described, so I cannot unlink it.

2) I go to dialog flow and force a change in some intent - this seams to unlink my account. So now when I open my action "ok google , talk to XYZ" it asks for account linking - however, after account linking it does not go to NEW_USER handler, it seams to remember that I am not a new user.

3) Go to my OAUTH server and logout the user - google assistant still remembers that user is not new user

4) Create a new OAUTH user from google home app while doing account linking - even then NEW_USER is not triggered. The google assistant still remembers and does not treat me as new user.

Is there a way to create conditions to test a new user on google home?

Just a side note, this is easy on Alexa. In Alexa app, if you disable your skill and re-enable it, all previous history is lost and NEW_USER is triggered. So I am able to test "first time user" condition for developing Alexa.

Answer (score 0):

We had success using the account linking URL provided in the Google Assistant Simulator and clicking on "unlink my accounts": https://gala-demo.appspot.com/